# MYSQL Foreign Key errno: 150 cannot create tables

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I've been reading around StackOverflow and various forums about this problem but I cannot seem to figure it out.  When trying to run the "CREATE TABLE Class" and "CREATE TABLE Enroll" commands below I get "ERROR 1005:  Can't create table university.class (errno: 150)".  I am using InnoDB as my storage engine.  The first two "CREATE" statements work fine.

What changes do I need to make so that the "CREATE TABLE Class and CREATE TABLE Enroll" sections work?

```
CREATE TABLE Student (
    stuId VARCHAR(6),
    lastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    firstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    major VARCHAR(10),
    credits FLOAT(3) DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT Student_stuId_pk PRIMARY KEY (stuId),
    CONSTRAINT Student_credits_cc CHECK ((credits>=0) AND (credits < 150)));

CREATE TABLE Faculty (
    facId VARCHAR(6),
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    department VARCHAR(20),
    rank VARCHAR(10),
    CONSTRAINT Faculty_facId_pk PRIMARY KEY (facId));

CREATE TABLE Class (
    classNumber VARCHAR(8),
    facId VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    schedule VARCHAR(8),
    room VARCHAR(6),
    CONSTRAINT Class_classNumber_pk PRIMARY KEY (classNumber),
    CONSTRAINT Class_facId_fk FOREIGN KEY (facId) REFERENCES Faculty
        (facId) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Class_schedule_room_uk UNIQUE (schedule, room));

CREATE TABLE Enroll (
    stuId VARCHAR(6),
    classNumber VARCHAR(8),
    grade VARCHAR(2),
    CONSTRAINT Enroll_classNumber_stuId_pk PRIMARY KEY
        (classNumber, stuId),
    CONSTRAINT Enroll_classNumber_fk FOREIGN KEY (classNumber)
        REFERENCES Class (classNumber) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT Enroll_stuId_fk FOREIGN KEY (stuId) REFERENCES Student
(stuId)ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Here is the full command and error:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Class (classNumber VARCHAR(8), facId VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, schedule VARCHAR(8), room VARCHAR(6), CONSTRAINT Class_classNumber_pk PRIMARY KEY (classNumber), CONSTRAINT Class_facId_fk FOREIGN KEY (facId) REFERENCES Faculty (facId) ON DELETE SET NULL, CONSTRAINT Class_schedule_room_uk UNIQUE (schedule, room));
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'university.Class' (errno: 150)
```

Comment: Could it be because facId in table 'class' is set to NOT NULL but in table 'Faculty' facId is not?

Comment: I tried adding "NOT NULL" to facId in the Faculty table and it made no difference in the other two commands.  Thanks for the idea but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate : [Mysql create table with multiple foreign key on delete set null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880070/mysql-create-table-with-multiple-foreign-key-on-delete-set-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove NOT NULL in defination of facId

Comment: Thank you, I'm embarrassed to see it was such a simple fix.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you created the Faculty Table first.
check this link

[inno db error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html)

which says if you get 1005 with error 150 this means

a foreign key constraint was not correctly formed

Answer (score 0):

This is occur due to a foreign keye error. To get more details on foreign key error, run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G and look at the "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" section.

I think it will tell that the foreign key is invalid because there is no unique index or primary key index on Faculty.facid.