# Update records with foreign keys when a record is deleted

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables, `Product` and `Category`. The relationship is `Product has a Category`. That means, the Primary Key of the `Category` table is the foreign key of the `Product` table. Product table has 2 columns, `Name` and `idCategory`.
I am using `MySQL InnoDB` as the database.

Now my question is this; imagine I delete the category "Fruits" in `Category` table. In my `Product` table, "Apple", "Orange" and "Grapes" are "Fruits". When I delete the Fruits from `Category`, the `idCategory` of the "Apple", "Orange" and "Grapes" in `Product` table should be set to `NULL`

Is there any automatic process in MySQL to do this?

Comment: You can use TRIGGERS

Comment: Another one with demo [*`Mysql create table with multiple foreign key on delete set null`*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880070/mysql-create-table-with-multiple-foreign-key-on-delete-set-null)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid: I do not agree with your decision on making this as `duplicate`. I need some example code with explanation to understand.

Comment: @Sniper i have also provided another link above your comment which has a demo too and the first one has explanation what else you need ?